# Display contact list images in Outsystems Mobile

Tags: image, listview, contacts, outsystems

How can I display the contacts images along with the numbers as like the contact list  from the device.I tried to display the image from  URL "content://com.android.contacts/contacts/" by using the 'Contacts Plugin'.But I can't fetch the image from that URL.The type of image is set as 'External URL'.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue but resolved it now
I have used below javascript and you must have FilePlugin as dependency for your module.

```
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL($parameters.ContactPhotoURI, onResolveSuccess, onResolveFail);

function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {

    fileEntry.file(function (file) {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {

            // Remove the data:image/jpeg, part of the returned value
            $parameters.ContactPhoto = evt.target.result.substring(evt.target.result.indexOf(',') + 1);


            $resolve();
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    }, onErrorReadFile);
}

function onResolveFail(error) {
    console.log("Error resolving Local File System URL " + JSON.stringify(error));
    $resolve();
}

function onErrorReadFile(error){
    console.log("ERRO!");
    console.log(error);
    $resolve();
}
```

Here ContantPhotoURI is the uri returned by ContactPlugin and ContactPhoto is binary data which can be loaded into Image.
If there is any doubt you can follow the discussion [here](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/26752/contact-image/)